# Can any part of an ffmpeg command use expressions?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am still learning how expressions work with ffmpeg, whether any part of a command can be using expression or not.

As an example, I have this command:

`ffmpeg -y -i input.mp3 -af "sofalizer=sofa=ClubFritz1.sofa:type=freq:radius=2:speakers='FL 45|FR 45|BL 45|BR 45'" output.mp3`

(The file `CubFritz1.sofa` can by the way be downloaded [here](https://www.sofaconventions.org/data/database/clubfritz/))

Which basically applies the sofalizer effect and specify that each channel should be heard / come from, the left side (45 degrees) of the audio.

This works as expected.

However, I cannot seem to get expressions working in the command at all.

For example this:

`ffmpeg -y -i input.mp3 -af "sofalizer=sofa=ClubFritz1.sofa:type=freq:radius=2:speakers='FL if(0, 45, 45)'|'FR if(0, 45, 45)'|'BL if(0, 45, 45)'|'BR if(0, 45, 45)'" output.mp3`

Which does an `if(0, 45, 45)` as a test, so regardless the outcome should be `45`, right?

However, when I run this command, it does not seem to work anymore, meaning the sound is not purely coming from the left side.

I have even tried changing the location of the single `'` in the command without luck:

`ffmpeg -y -i input.mp3 -af "sofalizer=sofa=ClubFritz1.sofa:type=freq:radius=2:speakers=FL 'if(0, 45, 45)'|FR 'if(0, 45, 45)'|BL 'if(0, 45, 45)'|BR 'if(0, 45, 45)'" output.mp3`

My question is, what are the rules for getting expressions working in an ffmpeg command?

How would the command be rewritten so that the `if(0, 45, 45)` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think expressions are not supported by `safalizer` options

Comment: Are you saying that each effect needs to support expressions?

Comment: Yes. Whether to support expression on its options is entirely up to each filter. The documentation explicitly states which filter options which support an expression as their values.